# Back to the previous activity

Tags: java, android

I have Three Activities (Home ,First , Second )

HomeScreen-->FirstActivity-->SecondActivity

```
Intent intentmap = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intentmap);
```

When I'm in SecondActivity and I click button back , it return to Home page ,I want to return back to the previousActivity , how can i do it ?

Comment: back button will lead to previous activity. do you call finish() in first activity by any chance?

Comment: You're calling `finish();` for sure after `startActivity(intentmap);`.

Comment: it doesn't lead me to it ; it lead me to the homeActivity

Comment: @user2673732 no enough details. post your first activity and second activity

Comment: @Raghunandan  write it in answer , in order to check the correct answer  ( I call it by error in OnPause())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments you must be calling `finish()` from your FirstActivity.

Pressing backbutton will lead you to previous activity.

When you navigate from FirstActivity to SecondActivity. Your FirstActivity is paused. Your second activity is put on back stack and takes focus.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

When you press back button your current activity in the back stack is popped and destroyed. The previous activity in the back stack takes focus.

I suggest you look at the activity lifecycle and the activity back stack for further details

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html